# virtual inheritance and protected members access

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I saw the example below in an SO question about preventing class inheritance, and I didn't understand why it should work : If I have a class "CTest" that inherits publicly CBase, the compilation fails because in constructor 'CTest::CTest()' 'CSealed::CSealed()' is protected. If I get rid off the virtual keyword, the compilation succeeds, why ?

```
class CSealed
{
protected:
CSealed()
{
}
};

class CBase : virtual CSealed
{
public:
 CBase() {
 }
};

class CTest : public CBase
{
public:
CTest() { std::cout << "TEST !!!!\n " << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: You appear to be using private inheritance there.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Private inheritance does not set up an is-a relationship.

Comment: If I get rid off the virtual keyword, the compilation succeeds, why ?

Comment: compiles fine for me (without removing `virtual`)

Comment: It compiles for me with or without `virtual` - what compiler and compiler version are you using?

Comment: With Cpp.sh (website) compilation fails, with IDEONE.com compilation succeeds.

Comment: http://ideone.com/uw4M3H

Comment: That isn't the code you posted here. You seem to be determined to waste our time.

Comment: it's the same, I just added CTest... and this scheme is supposed to prevent inheriting from a CBase class... it prevents inherting in www.cpp.sh compiler but not in with your compiler or ideone.com

Comment: "I just added CTest." So, it's not the same.

Comment: Ok, you're right I should be careful next time. Anyway, things are not clear with the virtual inheritance keyword. The behavior differ according to the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've posted,

```
class CSealed
{
protected:
    CSealed()
    {}
};

class CBase : virtual CSealed
{
public:
    CBase()
    {}
};
```

will not permit `CBase` to be derived from. That's because the virtual base class must be initialized by the (each) constructor of the most derived class. And since the virtual base is a `private` base class, it's not accessible to a class derived from `CBase`.

E.g., this class derivation,

```
class CTest
    : public CBase
{};
```

should not compile it `CTest` is ever instantiated.

However, as a matter of fact, while it fails to compile with Visual C++ 2015, it does compile with MinGW g++ 6.3.0, so in practice it's not entirely reliable.

Instead of this old C++03 technique you can just use C++11 `final`:

```
class CBase final
{
public:
    CBase()
    {}
};
```

Comment: with ideone, this scheme isn't efficient http://ideone.com/uw4M3H whereas it works with cpp.sh (compiler error)

Comment: @Aminos: I think you mean “isn't effective”, in that it doesn't work. I just tested with g++ 6.3.0 and it fails to detect the error with empty classes.

Comment: C++ code once struggle to compile everywhere hahaha.

Comment: btw, I know the final keyword, I just wanted to understand why the compiler generated an error... and finally we've seen that the compilation succeeds on some compiler whereas it fails on others. THANK YOU